# Pullback $p^*$ reflects isomorphisms implies $p$ is universal quotient map

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, descent

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$I'm trying to understand the implication $(i) \implies (ii)$ in the first theorem of ["How algebraic is the change-of-base functor by Janelidze and Tholen](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0084219), and I should preface this with "I'm not a topologist".
The statement is

> Let $p \colon E \to B$ be a morphism in $\newcommand{\Top}{\operatorname{Top}} \Top$.
> If the functor $p^* = E \times_B - \colon \Top/B \to \Top/E$ reflects isomorphisms, then $p$ is a universal quotient map.

Here:

- a functor $F \colon C \to D$ reflects isomorphisms if $Ff$ being an isomorphism implies that $f$ was already an isomorphism.
- $\Top/X$ is of course the category of spaces over $X$, i.e. tuples $(A, \alpha \colon A \to X)$ with morphisms $f \colon (A, \alpha) \to (C, \gamma)$ being morphisms of the underlying topological spaces satisfying $\gamma \circ f = \alpha$
- as the title implies, $E \times_B A$ for $(A, \alpha) \in \Top/B$ is the pullback of $E \xrightarrow{p} B \xleftarrow{\alpha} A$.
- *universal quotient map* basically means that first of all $p$ is a quotient map and that in any pullback $E \times_Z A$, the projection $\pi_2 \colon E \times_B A \to A$ is a quotient map.

Now, I practically don't understand most steps in the proof.
Here it is:

> 1. Let $A'$ be the set $\im \pi_2$ equipped with the quotient topology for $\pi_2$.
> 2. The inclusion $j \colon A' \to A$ is in $\Top/B$.
> 3. $E \times_B j$ is a homeomorphism, thus $j$ is a homeomorphism.
> 4. Thus $\pi_2$ is a quotient map.

My problems/troubles with this are:

- The general proof strategy seems to be to define a "quotient-like" map, and show that it is onto. But for that, they seem to be leaving out an assumption, right? Namely, that $p$ be a quotient map.  In particular, it's clear that if $p$ is not surjective, the map $\pi_2$ can only be onto if the image of $A \to B$ is contained in $\im p$.

So let's assume that $p$ is at least onto.

- In 2, why is $j \in \Top$? I'm not a topologist, and this is not trivial for me.
  I understand that for $U \in A$ open, I have to check that $\{(e,a) | a \in U\} \subset E \times_B A$ is open, but I don't get it.
- How to see that $E\times_B j$ is a homeomorphism?

---

**EDIT:**
Ok, so assuming that $j$ is continuous, I now understand why $E(j) = E \times_B j$ is a homeomorphism.
Let $(A, \alpha)$ in $\Top/B$.
We can consider the (set-theoretical) corestricted mapping $\pi_2' \colon E \times_B A \to A' = \im \pi_2$ (i.e. we simply restrict the target of $\pi_2$ to the image). Then we consider $A'$ with the final topology for $\pi_2'$, so it is *by construction* a quotient map.
Denote again the inclusion by $j \colon A' \to A$; if $j$ is continuous, then it is clear that also $(A', \alpha' = \alpha j) \in \Top/B$.
Note also that $\pi_2 = j \pi_2'$.

We claim that
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
E \times_B A @>{\pi_2'}>> A' \\
@V{\pi_1}VV @VV{\alpha'}V \\
E @>>{p}> B
\end{CD}
is a pullback.
So assume we have a span $E \xleftarrow{f} Q \xrightarrow{g}$ with $pf = \alpha' g$.
In other words, we have
\begin{align}
   p j = \alpha' g = \alpha (j g)
\ ,
\end{align}
thus there is a unique $u \colon Q \to E \times_B A$ such that
$$
  \pi_1 u = f \text{  and  } \pi_2 u = j g \ .
$$
But then $j \pi_2' u = j g$, and since $j$ is monic, $\pi_2' u = g$.
That is, $u$ satisfies
$$
  \pi_1 u = f \text{  and  } \pi_2' u = g \ ,
$$
so that the diagram is indeed a pullback diagram.
Thus $E \times_B A \cong E \times_B A'$.
In particular, $E \times_B j$ is an isomorphism, and so $j$ is an isomorphism, i.e.\ $A \cong A'$ and thus $\pi_2$ is a quotient map.

---

**EDIT 2:**
Continuity of $j$ is actually pretty easy, I think, at least if the following is correct.
Let $\pi_2'$ be as in the previous edit, i.e. the corestricted $\text{Set}$-map $\pi_2' = \pi_2 \colon E \times_B A \to A' = \im(\pi_2)$, and note that crucially $j \pi_2' = \pi_2$.
Also, $A'$ has final topology for $\pi_2'$.
But then
\begin{align*}
U \subset A \text{ open}
&\overset{\pi_2 \text{ cont.}}{\implies} \pi_2^{-1}(U) \text{ open}
\\
&\overset{(*)}{\iff} \pi_2^{-1}(U) = \pi_2'^{-1} \left( j^{-1} (U) \right) 
\text{ open}
\\
&\overset{\pi_2' \text{ quotient}}{\iff} j^{-1}(U) \text{ open}
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ is just the fact that taking preimages is a contravariant operation w.r.t. function composition.

Comment: What is $\text{Top}{/}B$ ? some category defined in terms of Top and $B$? What does it mean to "reflect isomorphisms" ? As often with category theory probably the statement is obvious once you really get all the terms.. Ditto with $\times_B$?

Comment: AFAIK you're not allowed to talk about images of maps etc. A quotient map is categorically defined by a universal property. Why would it need to be onto? That's (IMO) non-categorical thinking.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: $\text{Top}/B$ is the category of spaces over $B$, i.e. basically continuous maps to $B$, and "reflecting isomorphisms" just means if $E \times_B f$ is an iso, then $f$ is an iso.  (Note that I didn't ask about those steps in the proof, they're clear to me. Only topological things are a mysterium)

Comment: And what is $\times_B$? A special product? I cannot access that paper so I don't see the definitions. You should make a question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: $E \times_B A$ is the pullback (or fibered product), and the notation is standard, so it is self-contained - it's even in the title. I'm also not saying that the proof is supposed to be purely categorical. So, by not having any "categorical" expectations, I'm allowed to argue with $\text{Set}$-maps.  (and there epis split)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma All the notations and concepts here are very standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, observe that the class of morphisms $p : E \to B$ such that $p^* : \textbf{Top}_{/ B} \to \textbf{Top}_{/ E}$ is conservative (= reflects isomorphisms) is closed under pullback: this is essentially an application of the pullback pasting lemma.
Thus, if we wish to show that every morphism in this class is a universal quotient map, it suffices to show that every morphism in this class is a quotient map.

Let $B'$ be the image of $p : E \to B$, considered as a subspace of $B$, and consider the pullback of the inclusion $B' \hookrightarrow B$.
The pullback of a subspace inclusion is a subspace inclusion, and since $B'$ is the image of $p : E \to B$, the pullback of the inclusion must be $\textrm{id} : E \to E$ (up to isomorphism).
But $p^* : \textbf{Top}_{/ B} \to \textbf{Top}_{/ E}$ is conservative, so that implies $B' \hookrightarrow B$ is also an isomorphism, hence $p : E \to B$ is surjective.
(I am heavily abusing notation here.
Really I am speaking of the inclusion $B' \hookrightarrow B$ considered as a morphism from $B' \hookrightarrow B$, considered as an object in $\textbf{Top}_{/ B}$, to $\textrm{id}_B : B \to B$, which is a terminal object in $\textbf{Top}_{/ B}$, etc.)

We can play the same game with the image of $p : E \to B$ topologised as a quotient $\tilde{E}$ of $E$ instead of as a subspace of $B$.
The continuous map $p : E \to B$ factors as a quotient map $E \twoheadrightarrow \tilde{E}$ followed by an injective continuous map $\tilde{E} \to B$.
The pullback of $\tilde{E} \to B$ is a bijective continuous map $E \times_B \tilde{E} \to E$.
But in fact we have a continuous inverse map $E \to E \times_B \tilde{E}$, namely the map given by the universal property of pullbacks whose first component is $\textrm{id} : E \to E$ and whose second component is the quotient map $E \twoheadrightarrow \tilde{E}$.
Thus $E \times_B \tilde{E} \to E$ is an isomorphism, so $\tilde{E} \to B$ is also an isomorphism.
Hence $p : E \to B$ is indeed a quotient map.

(The second paragraph above is actually redundant – but I include it for pedagogical purposes.)

Comment: The fact that we have a "quotient-mono" factorization for continuous maps is blowing my mind right now. And thank you, so basically with all my edits and your answer as the final straw, the full proof works now. :) I'll accept your answer, but maybe also post a full answer myself eventually.